# IPC between unmanaged C++ and managed C# application using WCF and WWSAPI

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-c++, ipc, wwsapi

I want to achieve IPC between unmanaged VC++ COM Excel addin and managed C# console application. Currently I achieve IPC between maanged C# applications using NetNamedPipeBinding. I now want to achieve IPC between unmanaged and managed applications using NetNamedPipeBinding.

I tried using WWSAPIs and followed the sample at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38535/A-first-look-at-the-Windows-Web-Services-API?fid=1544433&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&select=4599321&tid=4692277) to achieve the same. As mentioned at MSDN reference [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [link3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) NetNamedPipeBinding is available for WWSAPIs and shipped with Windows 8 SDK.

Following is the code sample of my C# Console application

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/Server");
serverHost = new ServiceHost(this, baseAddress);

NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
binding.Security.Mode = NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None;

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy12;
serverHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

serverHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(), "mex");
serverHost.AddServiceEndpoint((typeof(IAdd)), binding, baseAddress);

serverHost.Open();
```

IAdd is the interface which is defined as follows

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAdd
{
    [OperationContract]
    void PerformAddition(int val1, int val2);
}
```

Then I start the service and execute the following command to generate wsdl and xsd files.

```
svcutil /t:metadata net.pipe://localhost/Server
```

After this I use WsUtil to create the required header files. However, when I try to create header files I get the following warning :

> warning WSUTIL0089  No supported policy setting has been found in the
>   input metadata. The service may be using a binding configuration not
>   supported by WWSAPI, such as message security setting. See
>   documentation for the list of configurations supported by WWSAPI.

Now If I change the binding type in my C# console application to WSHttpBinding or NetTcpBinding then I am successfully able to create the header files using WsUtil.

I cannot use WsHttpBinding as it required administrative previliges to start the service and typically my managed application will run with non administrative previliges. I also read on MSDN that Net Named Pipe Binding is optimized for IPC on same machine which is ideally my case.

If required I can share the sample code for my unamanged C++ and managed C#.

Any Help regarding acheiving NetNamedPipeBinding between unmanaged C++ and managed C# would be appreciated

P.S: I cannot port my unmanaged VC++ COM addin to managed VSTO application

Comment: Can you edit the main WSDL file and change the `soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/named-pipe" />` line. Just replace `named-pipe` by `tcp`. Wsutil should now work, but can you use what's generated then?